# Query works with Oracle 10g but not with 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ora-00979

```
DECLARE
  trn  VARCHAR2(2) := 'DD';
  cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR
    SELECT
      TRUNC(some_date, trn),
      NULL AS dummy_2,
      COUNT( DISTINCT dummy_1 )
    FROM
      (SELECT SYSDATE AS some_date, ROWNUM AS dummy_1 FROM dual)
    GROUP BY
      TRUNC(some_date, trn);
END;
```

This works with Oracle 10, but with `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production` it results in:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   ORA-06512: at line 5

---

Can anyone reproduce/explain this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using this for statistics where I want to decide if the records should be grouped by day or by hour.

Comment: Works ok on my 11gR2 (64-bit). Just in case, full banner:  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you have access to support, it looks like [Bug 9478304: LOOP FAILING WITH ORA-00979: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/ui/flash.html#tab=KBHome%28page=KBHome&id=%28%29%29,%28page=KBNavigator&id=%28bmDocTitle=LOOP%20FAILING%20WITH%20ORA-00979%3a%20NOT%20A%20GROUP%20BY%20EXPRESSION&bmDocType=BUG&viewingMode=1143&from=BOOKMARK&bmDocDsrc=BUG&bmDocID=9478304%29%29). This seems to affect 11.2.0.1 only.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot! The suggested workaround of the parent bug (`_optimizer_distinct_agg_transform = false`) solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that the `NULL` in your `SELECT` needs to be in the `GROUP BY` even though it is a constant. I can't imagine why it would work in Oracle 10 but not 11, though.

Does it work if you remove `NULL AS dummy_2`?

Comment: Yes, it works if I remove any part of the query, even the `DISTINCT`-keyword makes a difference. Grouping by `NULL` doesn't help...

Comment: The definitely sounds like a bug in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

This works without errors:

```
DECLARE
  trn  VARCHAR2(2) := 'DD';
  cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR
    SELECT
      TRUNC(some_date, dtrn),
      NULL AS dummy_2,
      COUNT( DISTINCT dummy_1 )
    FROM
      (SELECT SYSDATE AS some_date, ROWNUM AS dummy_1 FROM dual) data1,
      (SELECT trn AS dtrn FROM dual) data2
    GROUP BY TRUNC(some_date, dtrn);
END;
```

Problem is with `trn` variable and variable using in `TRUNC` function. Maybe it is bug.

Answer (score 1):

Truncating the sysdate in the inner select appears to work fine:

```
DECLARE
  trn  VARCHAR2(2) := 'DD';
  cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR
    SELECT
      some_date,
      NULL AS dummy_2,
      COUNT( DISTINCT dummy_1 )
    FROM
      (SELECT trunc(SYSDATE, trn) AS some_date, ROWNUM AS dummy_1 FROM dual)
    GROUP BY
      some_date;
END;
```